# Telegram BOT: как скопировать сообщение пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI.  Как присвоить переменной содержимое сообщения? Т.е. как получить текст сообщения, которое пользователь шлет боту?

Comment: `text = message.text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо реализовать функцию "отлавливания" сообщений текстового типа таким способом:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_message(message):
   string = message.text
```

У класса message, который представляет собой пользовательское сообщение, есть поле text, которое хранит текст сообщения. Именно это поле мы будем присваивать переменной.